# Download html generated by script

Tags: javascript, delphi, download

If I manually click on `button1` and then on `button2` I get the whole html code (410 KiB). However If I try to automate this process with the code below, I only get a part of it, without the html generated by javascript (40 KiB).

Yes, I tried putting form1.Button2.Click; OnDocumentComplete, but still only 40 KiB were written. Is there any way to wait for execution of javascript as well?

Ps. Do not take this code too seriously. I just what to learn few things with a simple dirty example code.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

  form1.EmbeddedWB1.Navigate('https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/87101-terminator-genisys/posters');

  while EmbeddedWB1.ReadyState < READYSTATE_COMPLETE do Application.ProcessMessages;

  form1.Button2.Click;

end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var Doc: IHtmlDocument2;
begin

  Doc := EmbeddedWB1.Document as IHtmlDocument2;
  Memo1.Lines.Text := Doc.body.innerHTML;
  memo1.Lines.SaveToFile('C:\...\MoviePosters.html');

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following - note that I'm using a vanilla TWebBrowser not a TEmbeddedWB - seems to do what you ask, at least for that specific URL.  It's based purely on observation of the ProgressChange event and I've not tested it on any other URLs.  Hopefully someone will be able to post you a more general and less fragile solution.

```
procedure TForm1.LogHTML;
var
  Doc: IHtmlDocument2;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Clear;
  Doc := WebBrowser1.Document as IHtmlDocument2;
  if (Doc <> Nil) and (Doc.body <> Nil) then
    Memo1.Lines.Text := Doc.body.innerHTML;
  Caption := Format('Length: %d', [Length(Memo1.Lines.Text)]);
end;

procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1ProgressChange(Sender: TObject; Progress,
    ProgressMax: Integer);
begin
  if (Progress = 0) and (ProgressMax = 0) then
    LogHTML;
end;
```

Of course, the JS could go on writing to the document forever, so you might want to use a TTimer's OnTimer event to re-read the document's HTML.

Btw, I realise you're just "messing about" in your code but avoid referring to Form1's methods in one of TForm1's methods.  `TForm1` is a *class*, whereas `Form1` is a specific instance of it, which may or may not have been created when the `TForm1` method executes, and this crucial difference will come back to bite you eventually.  Suppose, f.i. that the actual instance of `TForm1` your using is `MyOtherForm`.